# How to use precision or f1-score metrics in TensorFlow for multiclass classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have tried to reproduce the following code for a multiclass classification problem (3 classes) from here:
https://saturncloud.io/blog/multiclass-logistic-regression-with-tensorflow-20-a-comprehensive-guide/

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load the Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()

# Split the dataset into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

I noticed that when I change the line in `model.compile` with

```
metrics=['accuracy']
```

to

```
 metrics=[ tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
```

to  get a precision metric instead of accuracy, the code gives an error about shapes:

```
ValueError: Shapes (32, 3) and (32, 1) are incompatible
```

Error also happens if I try to add precision as a metric after accuracy like so:

```
metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision()]
```

I have also tried tensorflow addons and again get an error:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
metrics= [tfa.metrics.F1Score(average="macro",num_classes = 3,threshold=None,name='f1_score', dtype=None)]

ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1. Shapes are [3] and [1].
```

How can I optimize on precision or f1-score from TensorFlow metrics (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to one-hot encode the labels to be able to use the different metrics:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
print(tf.__version__)
# 2.13.0

# Load the Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()

# Split the dataset into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Encode the labels
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)
encoder.fit(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_train = encoder.transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test = encoder.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))

# Scale the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Define the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=[
        'accuracy',
        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
        tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
        tf.keras.metrics.F1Score(average='macro'),
    ]
)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
# Epoch 1/5
# 4/4 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 1.0046 - accuracy: 0.4000 - precision: 0.8605 - recall: 0.3083 - f1_score: 0.2824
# Epoch 2/5
# 4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9873 - accuracy: 0.4167 - precision: 0.9048 - recall: 0.3167 - f1_score: 0.3060
# Epoch 3/5
# 4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9719 - accuracy: 0.4167 - precision: 0.9286 - recall: 0.3250 - f1_score: 0.3049
# Epoch 4/5
# 4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9555 - accuracy: 0.4250 - precision: 0.9756 - recall: 0.3333 - f1_score: 0.3160
# Epoch 5/5
# 4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9396 - accuracy: 0.4250 - precision: 0.9756 - recall: 0.3333 - f1_score: 0.3160

# Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
# 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 294ms/step - loss: 0.9422 - accuracy: 0.4667 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 0.3333 - f1_score: 0.3903
```

Note that the `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` loss is replaced by the `'categorical_crossentropy'` loss given that the labels are now one-hot encoded.